# How do I resize mounts on my CentOS VM?

Tags: linux, vmware-fusion, centos, partition, mount

I'm running VMWare Fusion on my Mac, and just created a new VM for CentOS 5.3.  I have pre-allocated 20GB of space for this VM.

Here are the / and /home mounts on my machine.  There are others but they should be inconsequential.

```
[root@localhost ~]# df -h
Filesystem  Size  Used  Avail  Use%  Mounted on
/dev/sda2   3.8G  3.8G      0  100%  /
/dev/sda5   9.8G  1.1G   8.2G   12%  /home
```

I want to resize the /home partition to ~4GB, and resize the / partition to ~10GB.  How would I go about this?  Are there any limitations as a result of the fact that I'm running this on a VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have experience with VMWare Fusion in particular, but with other VMs I have run the process to expand a partition is much the same as a physical system. After you shut down the VM and increase the "physical" hard drive space on the VM, boot with [**Parted Magic**](http://partedmagic.com/) or other partition growing boot disk of choice, and resize the partitions to the sizes you want.

Boot back normally into the VM and you are done.